# jQuery masonry issue with display and height on load

Tags: javascript, css, height, jquery-masonry

I have a masonry container inside of a div that has `display:none` in inline style. Because I have a few divs, when the page loads it switches like a slideshow when their button is clicked. This interferes with masonry's ability to gauge the height on load so consequently the bricks spill out of the container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** the `.load()` part of my answer is not how this should be done.

**See:** http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#imagesloaded

---

You can fix it by:

- Adding `overflow: hidden` to `.panel` to [clear the floated elements](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) inside.
- <strike>Running Masonry on [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) instead of [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):</strike>

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).load(function (){
        $('#contain').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.item',
          columnWidth: 100
        });
      });
  </script>
  ```

<strike>Version with those fixes: http://jsbin.com/oyido4/4</strike>

Comment: perfect! thanks. i knew about using overflow to clear floated elements but it was running masonry on LOAD that got it done.

Comment: See the update to my answer. `.load()` does work, but it will keep Masonry waiting for everything on the page to be loaded, instead of just the images inside `#contain`.